# Swift firebase snapshot returns null when data exists

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to simply fetch all notifications from my firebase database that have the child value that equals my postId. I know for a fact that it exists and if I try it a few times it eventually returns the snapshot. What might be the issue here?

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("notification").child(postUserId).queryOrdered(byChild: postId).queryEqual(toValue: postId)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot.value)
        }
```

[image: Database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("notification").child(postUserId).queryOrdered(byChild: postId).queryEqual(toValue: postId)
```

into this:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("notification").child(postUserId).queryOrdered(byChild: "postId").queryEqual(toValue: postId)
```

add quotations to the `postId` in the query

Comment: Good catch. OP, keep in mind that your code (and this answer) will only query nodes in the parent node of *JnHYOR...*. If that's the intention then you're set with this answer. If you want to query nodes at the same parent level as *JnHYOR...*, it won't work and you will need either a deep query or denormalize your data.